# C passing a pointer of an array to a function getting different results

Tags: c, pointers

I'm fairly new to C and having trouble with this code.

```
int * choose(int * got, int n_chosen, int len, int max_types, int n, int states, int * comb){
    int i;
    if (n_chosen == len) {
            if (!got) return NULL;

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                comb[len*n + i] = times[got[i]];
                printf("%d\n",comb[len*n + i] );
                }
            ++n;
            return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < max_types; i++) {
            if (got) got[n_chosen] = i;
            choose(got, n_chosen + 1, len, max_types, n, states, comb);
    }
    return comb;
}
```

In the main I have the following code:

```
int num_states = (int) pow(4.0,(double)lab->color_count);
int num = lab->room_count * num_states;

int chosen[4];
int * combinations =  malloc(sizeof(int)*num_states*lab->color_count);
choose(chosen, 0, lab->color_count, 4, 0, num_states, combinations);

int a, b;

for(b=0; b < num_states; ++b){
    for(a = 0; a < lab->color_count; ++a){
        //printf("%d\t", combinations[b*lab->color_count + a]);
        printf("%d\t", combinations[b*lab->color_count + a]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The problem is when I print the array in the fuction I get the correct values but when printing it in the main random values get printed. As far as I understood I was passing a pointer so the values should be the same. Could someone please explain me what is happening and how to fix this?

Extra information: The method is for calculating the combinations.

## EDIT: MVCE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int times[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
long choose(int * got, int n_chosen, int len, int max_types, int n, int states, int * comb){
        int i;
        long count = 0;
        if (n_chosen == len) {
                if (!got) return 1;

                for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    comb[len*i + n] = times[got[i]];
                    printf("%d\n",comb[len*i + n] );
                }
                return 1;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < max_types; i++) {
                if (got) got[n_chosen] = i;
                count += choose(got, n_chosen + 1, len, max_types, n, states, comb);
                ++n;
        }
        return count;
}

int main(){
        int num_states = 4;

        int chosen[4];
        int * combinations =  malloc(sizeof(int)*num_states*1);
        choose(chosen, 0, 1, 4, 0, num_states, combinations);
        printf("\n");
        int a, b;
        for(b=0; b < 1; ++b){
            for(a = 0; a < num_states; ++a){
                printf("%d\n", combinations[b*2 + a]);
            }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

## I have edited the MVCE with a working code in case anyone ever needs this.

Comment: Was that what you were asking for?

Comment: In the MCVE, `combinations[b*2 + a]` accesses out of bounds. You malloc'd 4 ints, but this prints indices 0,2,4,6

Comment: in the MCVE, you only ever write to `comb[0]`.  To debug your code, use a debugger, or add extra print statement to show which index you are writing , each time you print what you wrote

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I feel really stupid.

Comment: I pasted the MCVE into a file and compiled it and ran it and it works fine.

Comment: Your MCVE doesn't look very M... What does valgrind say?

Comment: @LoretoPrieto if your question has been answered, the right thing to do is to post an answer to the question and accept it.  Or perhaps if "M.M"'s comments were all it took to fix your problem, then suggest to "M.M" to turn them into an answer, so that you can accept it.  It is not a good idea to edit the question with working code, because it will be very confusing to anyone who views this in the future.